# Why my block does not appear on specific page?

Tags: blocks

I have a menu. This menu is a block: **my_block_menu**.

I want to assign **my_block_menu** certain pages, not all. For this, I'm going to block *Visibility options* and select *Only the listed pages*.
So, I write the pages path. Result: The block appears on all pages, except one listed. Why block on this page does not appear?

After trying many things, I tried the *PHP option (experts only)*. And I put this code:

```
$a = 1;
if (!empty($a)) {
    return true;
}
else return true;
```

Result: **Block not shown in this page!**
What's going on? I'm going crazy!

Comment: Exactly which paths did you specify in the visibility options? On which URL does the block not appear, and is that a system path or a path alias? Did you double-check that there are no other visibility rules active? Did you enable modules or themes that modify blocks, implement [hook_block_list_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7), or influence the visibility of (or access to) menu items?

Comment: @marcvangend:
The block is not shown on this page: primaria/producto/ob. This page is a Views view.

1) Exactly which paths did you...
primaria/*
node/108
node/108/*

2) On which URL does the block not appear...
?q=primaria/producto/ob
It's path alias.

3) Did you double-check...
Yes. In the whole site, I just use that visibility option: Only pages listed.

4) Did you enable modules or themes...
I guess so. But I do not know exactly which modules modified blocks. Here is the complete list of my modules.
[link]http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/modules.jpg
My theme is Bootstrap

Comment: You write `primaria/producto/ob` is a path alias - so do you mean that the real path of the view (the path you enter in the Views interface under `Page Settings > Path` like in [this image](http://www.leccionespracticas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/path_breadcrumbs_in_views_page_0.jpg)) is different? What does it say? Did you try adding that path to the block settings?

Comment: 1) What does it say? [This](http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/path.jpg). 2) Did you try adding that path to the block settings? Yes, [I tried it](http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/path2.jpg) And the block does not appear.

Comment: OK. (Nit pick: that means "primaria/producto/ob" is technically not a path alias, but the path of a view.) As far as I can see your block is configured correctly. The only possible remaining cause I can think of, is that the block is empty on this specific page. You would have to go into the code generating the block output (a hook_block_view implementation), see if it generates output, and if not find out why.

Comment: I experienced several problems with my Drupal. Display suite fails, Webform fails, and the blocks are not shown! I think I'm guilty! I installed too many contributed modules. I suspect that interfere with each other. Or that one of them (maybe a alfa/beta version) is the cause of all my troubles!

It is the first time I use Drupal. I think it is not good idea to install too many contributed modules. :(

Comment: Possibly, yes. In my experience your number of modules is large, but not necessarily *too* large. What the modules do, and how they're configured, is much more important than the module count. It sometimes does happen that modules interfere with each other. The best way to find out is to disable them one by one, or use a step debugger like Xdebug to find the cause of your problem. That however is beyond the scope of this question.